# Why will JavaFX not work in Eclipse for me?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

**Eclipse Version:** 2019-09

**JavaFX Version:** Eclipse Marketplace Install

I have tried to install JavaFX in Eclipse but every time I make a new project I keep getting weird results and I have no idea how to fix it to start working on my projects.

[image]

In this first image, this is what I am seeing after making a new project.

[image]

If I change the JRE to jre1.8.0_221 the error messeges go away but then I get this error:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I know that this is an issue with versions when switching to jre 1.8. I am using the JavaFX installation from the Eclipse marketplace.

What am i doing wrong here and how can I fix this?

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: application/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 57.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full stack trace as text, not as an image.  Images of text are hard to read, unsearchable, and cannot be understood by sight impaired users.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: After switching to Java 8, did you clean and rebuild your application?  The message indicates you are running with Java 8 (which uses class file version 52), but your compiled .class files were made for Java 13 (which uses class file version 57).

Comment: I want to use Java 13. I installed an updated version of eclipse and installed Java 13, then when I go to make a JavaFX project in eclipse with Java 13 selected as my deafult JRE/JDK, it just says that all the JavaFX imports are like non existent or something.

Comment: First of all I don't know what you have installed because there is no JavaFX installation in the marketplace. Have a look here and follow the instructions for Eclipse: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: When you type javafx into the marketplace it give you an option for e(fx)eclipse.  Also, I viewed those docs but they didnt help me install it and use it with eclipse. I couldn't follow what they were saying to do.